# Conditional minimum of 4D matrix: find minimizing vectors

Tags: python, numpy, linear-algebra, minimization

I'm guessing about the way to conditionally minimize the 4D matrix.

Let's start creating some toy data (which is close to my real-world problem):

```
import numpy as np

t = np.arange(1960,1981,1)
N = np.arange(0,3,1)

k = np.arange(0,5,0.1)
k_matrix = ( np.tile(k,(len(N),1)).T * (N+1)/(N+2) ).T

p = np.arange(0.1,2.01,0.1)

theory = np.random.normal(10,1,[len(N),len(t),len(p)])

res2 = np.zeros([len(N),len(t),len(k),len(p)])

def calc_res2(N,t,k_matrix,p,theory):
    for N_ind, N_val in enumerate(N):
        for t_ind, t_val in enumerate(t):
            for k_ind, k_val in enumerate(k_matrix[N_ind]):
                for p_ind, p_val in enumerate(p):
                    res2[N_ind,t_ind,k_ind,p_ind] = (N_val*t_val-k_val*theory[N_ind,t_ind,p_ind])**2

    return res2

test = calc_res2(N,t,k_matrix,p,theory)
```

I want to find such indices/values of `k_matrix` (as a function of `N`) and `p` (as a function of `t`) that
`test` sum over `t` and `N` will be minimal.

Now I see that this problem can be solved using `for` cycles:

```
def k_multi_N (test,k_matrix,p):
    SUM_best = 1e99
    k0i_b,k1i_b,k2i_b = 0,0,0
    for k0_ind,k0 in enumerate(k_matrix[0]):
        temp = test[0,:,k0_ind,:] 
        for k1_ind,k1 in enumerate(k_matrix[1]):
            temp += test[1,:,k1_ind,:] 
            for k2_ind,k2 in enumerate(k_matrix[2]):
                temp += test[2,:,k2_ind,:] 

                SUM = sum(temp.min(axis=1))
                if SUM < SUM_best:
                    SUM_best = SUM
                    p_min_ind = np.argmin(temp,axis=1)
                    k0i_b,k1i_b,k2i_b = k0_ind,k1_ind,k2_ind

                temp -= test[2,:,k2_ind,:]
            temp -= test[1,:,k1_ind,:] 
        temp -= test[0,:,k0_ind,:]  

    return p_min_ind, (k0i_b,k1i_b,k2i_b)

k_multi_N (test,k_matrix,p)
```

So the expected output is:

```
(array([12, 16, 14,  8, 14, 18,  1, 18,  9,  9, 15, 18,  9, 13,  9,  3,  3,
        18, 13,  6, 19]),
 (0, 49, 49))
```

but the computational efficiency will be very small considering big-size vectors of `N` and `k` (my real-world case is 16*200 for `N*k`+800*200 for 't*k`, so it will be 16^200 iterations with 800*200 matrices :(

Of course, I considered `numba` solution, but it does not allow me to significantly speed up the calculation (i.e. it still takes a lot of time!).

I'm wondering about alternative, more computationally efficient ways to solve the problem.
Thanks!

EDIT: The question was significantly changed to clarify the problem. I appreciate the people who helped me to do it!

Comment: `t`, `p`, `N` and `k` are all constants in your code. I therefore don't understand what points 1 and 2 mean.

Comment: I have tried to clarify the wording, hope now it looks more convenient.

Comment: Perhaps to clarify your intent, try with an even simpler setup, and provide the expected output. For instance: `t,N,p,k = 2,3,4,5; test = np.arange(t*N*p*k).reshape([t,N,p,k])`

Comment: The wording 'argmin' is confusing here and I do not see how the dimensions of v1 and v2 would be what you say